# SwiftUI List header and subheader

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

The goal is for me to have a `List` section with a bold header and non-bold sub-header, which is something I couldn't figure out how to do. So I tried making the header with a `Text` view that contains text that is partially bold, and partially normal non-bold text.

I tried doing this with an `NSAttributedString` which works with a `UILabel` but it doesn't appear to work with swiftUI's `Text` object.

Im making the header like so:

```
Section(header: Text(docSection.formattedHeader)) {
    ...
```

where `docSection.formattedHeader` is an `NSAttributedString` that is half bold, half non-bold separated with a `\n`

however then I get the following error:

```
Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'NSAttributedString' conform to 'StringProtocol'
```

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `NSAttributedString` is incompatible with `SwiftUI` (yet), you should use `Text` instead. But for `Section`, You can use any `View` in. So why don't you use a `stackView` like this:

```
Section(header:
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("Header").fontWeight(.bold)
        Text("Subheader").fontWeight(.regular)
    }
) {
    Text("Content")
}
```

Also you can use `HStack` or any other combined views.

Comment: Thanks! This does the trick, don't know why I thought I could only use text as the header

Comment: Maybe because of the old `UITableView` method: `titleForHeaderInSection...`.

Comment: @Quinn do you know how to display header and subheader inside _List_ item? Trying  _List{ ForEach{ VStack{ Text  Text }}}_ doesn't compile..